# Python Function: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tuple' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function, tuples

The first block of code works (lines 15 - 21).

The error is occurring in the second block (lines 24 - 30).

###### Here is my code:

```py
# converting numerical input into list and tuple <-- line 15

data = input("provide numbers separated by ',': ")
list = data.split(",")
tuple = tuple(list)

print("list:", list, "tuple:", tuple)


def convert(): # <-- line 24
    data = input("provide numbers separated by ',': ")
    list = data.split(',')
    tuple = tuple(list)
    print("list:", list, "tuple:", tuple)

convert()
```

I have read solutions that suggest declaring the variable in the global namespace, but the solutions do not seem to be working for my function. And a solution still eludes me.

The function has the same code as the first block, its just wrapped in a function. I don't understand why the code works at the top level, but not inside a function.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: Sabrina, just for the future, it's *much* preferred if you post code as text rather than images. I've fixed that in this question.

Comment: Why are so many people asking about tuples? Is this part of a Computer Science class or online course thing?

Comment: So programming is just a whole bunch of abstract concepts jubled together, and implimented in a way that they can be applied to real life stuff. Throughout your programming journy, you will continue to learn concepts, even after programming for years. The concepts will get more complex, but eventually they will become easy for you to grasp. The trick to learning programming quickly, and to learn in a way that you build a solid foundation from which you can write code professionally is to understand exactly where you are at skill wise.

Comment: Its important to understand what concepts you should be learning. The reason I am telling you this, is because @paxdiablo gave a really great answer. He described the concepts you need to work at understanding thoroughly. If you can grasp what he is saying, and impliment it in your code to make your example work, you will probably start to have epiphanies, and things will start to become very very clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you *re-bind* a non-global variable name (such as `a = b`) anywhere within a function<sup>(1)</sup>, it is made a local variable for that entire function (even before the modification).

That means that `tuple = tuple(list)` is assigning to a local `tuple`, and your use of `tuple(list)` is using that *variable*, rather than the actual built-in `tuple()` function. Since that variable name is not bound at this point, you get the "use before set" error.

This is why it's a bad idea to use built-in function names as variable names, which is something you appear to have done with abandon, both `tuple` ***and*** `list` :-)

So I would suggest two things:

- rename your variables to prevent clashes (use `my_list` and `my_tuple` for example).
- make `my_tuple` global within the function (better would be to avoid globals altogether).

Avoiding globals can be as simple as:

```py
def convert():
    data = input("provide numbers separated by ',': ")
    my_list = data.split(",")
    my_tuple = tuple(my_list)
    print("list:", my_list, "tuple:", my_tuple)
    return my_tuple

outer_tuple = convert()
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> This does not include simply modifying the variable's value such as changing one item in a list:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]
x[1] = 42         # Mutation of x, not re-binding.
x = [7, 8, 9]     # Re-binding x to new object.
```

And note that for *immutable* types (like `int` for example), `x = 7` is *re-binding* `x` to a different object `7`, not changing the value of the object "behind" `x`. This particular aspect of Python (the fact that all things are objects and variable names are simply bound to those objects) was one of my greatest epiphanies when learning the language.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! So are you suggesting I change the variable name from 'tuple' to something else because its getting confused? Or is it that i should not be using a built in function inside a defined function

Comment: @SabrinaTes: the former. It's perfectly okay to use `tuple()` within a function, the problem here is that, since you have created a local variable called `tuple`, the function can no longer *see* the built-in function. It will instead attempt to call the variable as if it were a function (or other `Callable` type).

Comment: _If you modify a variable anywhere within a function_ Better to say "assign" rather than "modify".

Comment: @John, yes, let me fix that ...

Comment: wow. that helped so much. I have been fiddling around / trial-and-error to try and grasp the idea but can only assume time is the solution. Thanks for the edit - this is my first time posting on stack so now i will know!!

Comment: This is a really really great answer. Like really great. Its such a fundamental subject, but you did really well explaining it with crystal clarity. Answers this good, for fundamental topics like this one, are very rare.